# Can I make the divider of a JSplitPane stay in fixed location?

Tags: java, swing

I am using a splitpane and I want to fix the divider, such that it doesn't move at all. Is it possible ?

Comment: Sounds like you don't need a JSplitPane at all. Why not just use a BorderLayout instead?

Comment: It's sounds like you're defeating the purpose of a JSplitPane.  Just use 2 different JPanels decorated with Borders, or just use a JSeparator.

Answer (score 4):

Try disabling the divider, the content will still be enabled:

```
  divider.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: ya, that's what I meant...don't think you could disable the actual divider itself.  I assumed "JSplitPane divider = new JSplitPane()"  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide divider using BasicSplitPaneUI:

```
BasicSplitPaneDivider divider = ((BasicSplitPaneUI) impl.getUI()).getDivider();
if (!enabled) {
    divider.setDividerSize(0);
} else {
    divider.setDividerSize(10);
}
```